# Generalized Eigenvectors when algebraic multiplicity greater than 1

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

Find the Generalized Eigenvectors of 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Since for $\lambda = 0, null(A-\lambda I) = 2.$ I have 2 eigenvectors = 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\0\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}
and
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\0\\1\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I know to use $(A - \lambda I)v_2 = v_1$ to get all eigenvectors corresponding to a $\lambda$. But this one has 2 blocks corresponding to $\lambda = 0$ in the Jordan Cannonical form.
$$
J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So, how do I associate generalised eigenvectors to each Jordan block?

Comment: What is  generalised eigenvector?

Comment: Assuming that you know how to calculate general eigenvectors, how long is the Jordan chain for each of the eigenvectors of zero that you’ve got?

Comment: For eigenvalue = 0 it's 1 and 3, For eigenvalue = 1 it's 1

Comment: It is geometric multiplicity which is two. Not the algebraic multiplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first Jordan block is the one-by-one matrix [1].  An associated eigenvector is *x* = [–1, –1, –1, –1, 1]$^{\mathrm T}.$  The multiplicity of that eigenvalue is one, so there are no complications here.

Dealing with eigenvalue 0 is not as easy.  The remainder of my answer is based on Wikipedia subtopic ["Computation of generalized eigenvectors."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Computation_of_generalized_eigenvectors)

Because rank(*A* – 0 *I*) = rank *A* = 3, rank *A*$^2$ = 2, and rank *A*$^3$ = 1, there will be three linearly-independent generalized eigenvectors—*z*$_3$ of order 3, *z*$_2$ of order 2, and *z*$_1$ of order 1—that form a chain. To find *z*$_3,$ we solve *A*$^3$*z*$_3$ = 0 such that *A*$^2$*z*$_3$ ≠ 0.  The simplest solution is *z*$_3$ = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]$^{\mathrm T}.$  Then *z*$_2$ = *Az*$_3$ = [0, –1, –1, –1, 1]$^{\mathrm T},$ and *z*$_1$ = *Az*$_2$ = [0, 0, 0, –1, 0]$^{\mathrm T}.$  Those three generalized eigenvectors are associated with the third, three-by-three Jordan block.

Finally, note that *z*$_1$ is a multiple of the first eigenvector that you give.  Hence, you can associate the other eigenvector *y* = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]$^{\mathrm T}$ with the second, one-by-one Jordan block [0].

FYI, the Jordan decomposition *A = S J S*$^{-1}$ has *S* = [*x*, *y*, *z*$_1,$ *z*$_2,$ *z*$_3]$ where the generalized eigenvectors are the columns of *S*.